# Trying to center 2 groups of 2 divs each at the middle of a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have four divs(all same sizes) i have grouped them into to blocks of 2 with classes `blocka` both contained in an inner container `body-content` float all the blocks to the left so when my page width changes,these the blocks(of 2) aligned under each other.
I am trying to get now is that those divs sit right at the middle of the `main` container.

Everything response well. All i need it the class `body content` sit at the middle of `main` while `blocka` all center themselves in the middle of `body-content`

```css
.main {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 240px;
  background-color: ;
}

.body-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
}

.blocka {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` doesn't work with `float:left;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand so please clarify.

Here you go, the `body-content` is sitting in the middle of `main`, while `blocka` is sitting in the middle of `body-content`. You didn't said where will the `main` be position so I left it in the right-side.

Colors are for visualization and I reduced the `body-content`'s width to see the `main` behind it

```css
.main {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.body-content {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. this one works well  ,only problem is that the blocka does not restrict them selves in the main container vertically. class body-content should increase in height to always contain the blocka when they break. Any way that can happen? thanks

Comment: yes the main should be at the center as well @Swellar; Ur css workls just that i want body-content to increase in height at break points to allways accommodate the blocka. @Swellar:

Comment: I removed `margin-left` and added `margin: 0 auto` to center the `main`. I also decreased the `max-width` so that you can see that the main is really centered

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```css
.main {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: ;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
}

.blocka {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered flexbox?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.body-content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.blocka {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body-content-items {
  min-width: 35vw;
  min-height: 35vh;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocka">
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
      <div class="body-content-items">Add All</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Feel free to set fixed sizes for items (instead of `35vw/35vh`). I was just showing you it's possible. Changing their size will keep them centered.

Answer (score 2):

The body-content in this instance is the container.. Anytihng inside body will be flexed as defined..

```
.body-content{    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column
}

.blocka {
    flex:1
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please tick my answer as correct so other people looking at the post can find the answer quickly.. have fun with flexbox